Testing the predictive power of a time series signal
Given a signal from an unknown source/origins and some financial close price data, what are some straightforward ways to test for the signal's predictive power? Would I need to make both series stationary before doing any sort of regression/correlation analysis?
One potential method I have in mind is to transform the Adj Close into returns and transform the Signal by diffing it to make both series stationary, and then regressing the next day returns (T+1) on the diffed signal today (T - (T-1)) - not sure if how correct this is and what difference this makes than if I were to just regress next day returns (T+1) on todays signal (T). Would really appreciate some advice for this one!
What other methods are there for a task like this?
Signal data:

Close price data:

